# jCarousel issue : No width/height set

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, jquery-events, jcarousel

I am using jCarousel and during testing on iPad Safari, I get the alert

> jCarousel: No width/height set for items. This will cause an infinite loop. Aborting...

The JS can be found at;
http://ipad.atwebpages.com/carousellite.js

This issue occurs during some drag/drop action..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [this](http://drupal.org/node/228949) helps. Usually it's very important to set a width and height in the CSS.